# Was the small Vanuatu Tsunami detected by remote monitors in the ocean before it reached land?

Tags: tsunami

The 20-Nov-2017 Reuters News item [Small tsunamis detected in New Caledonia and Vanuatu after magnitude 7 undersea quake](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-newcaledonia-quake/small-tsunamis-detected-in-new-caledonia-and-vanuatu-after-magnitude-7-undersea-quake-idUSKBN1DJ0W0) says:

> Small tsunamis were detected and waves may have reached up to one meter (three feet) above the high tide level in parts of New Caledonia and smaller in Vanuatu, the PTWC said.

The PTWC is the [The Pacific Tsunami Warning Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Tsunami_Warning_Center).

Were Tsunami-like changes in sea level detected automatically and forwarded to some center before they reached any shoreline, or does "detected" refer to the relatively small tsunami wave shown in (for example) [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DK1-QgwPsEQ) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBquGF4EJ8g) YouTube video?